# Issue with OAuth 2 and Invision Community's API [Node.js]

Tags: php, node.js, oauth-2.0

I'm having an issue while trying to get the access token from my Invision's
personal forum API with OAuth 2, via the auth code grant.

When using Node.js's passport module with the passport-oauth2 strategy,
I don't receive the access token.

And I tried it without using passport. In this case, I correctly
get the auth code, but when I send the auth code with the rest of
the needed params as a request to the token url, I don't get a
token back. I have tried sending the params in the body of the
request, and urlencoded, with no results.

This doesn't happen with PHP. I tried making a $curl request
with PHP (using Laravel) and correctly got the access token.

I will share both blocks of code, the one in PHP that correctly
retrieves the access token; and the Node.js code which I can't
get to retrieve it. Am I doing something different in Node.js, that
makes my request invalid when comparing it with the PHP one?

// PHP working request //

```
$post_data = array(
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'code' => $code,
    'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
    'client_id' => $client_id,
    'client_secret' => $client_secret,
);

$curl = curl_init( $accTokenUrl );
curl_setopt_array( $curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post_data,
) );

$response = curl_exec( $curl );
$response = json_decode($response, true);
$accToken = $response['access_token'];

curl_close( $curl );
```

// End PHP

// Node.js not working request //

```
const res = await fetch(`https://myweb.io/forum/oauth/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=${code}&client_id=${client_id}&redirect_uri=${redirect_uri}&client_secret=${client_secret}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
});
```

// End Node.js

If any additional info would help solve my issue, please, tell me.

Thanks in advance for reading me, I know that this may be a
very specific concern.